# System calls programmatically [React-Native]

Tags: android, react-native

How to implement system calls or hardware calls like shutdown , restart ,open an app .

If i want to open camera i can use some camera plugin for react-native and use that code.

But how can open an app or shutdown my phone programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an app, you can try below snippet, and the rational for this is to start an implicit intent in Android, which will fire an app, provided that the app you want to start has implemented that:

```
 const pageId = 'abc123'
 Linking.openURL(`fb://profile/${pageId}`)
     .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

You can also try canOpenURL to test if you can **really** open that app:

```
Linking.canOpenURL(url)  
.then((supported)=>{  
  if (!supported){  
    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);  

  }else{  
    return Linking.openURL(url);  
  }  
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.let me try with this.